# Is there a way to find where a channel was and put it back to the same place?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

sorry for another question but is there a way to find where a channel was? So like if i deleted a channel called 'memes' it would remake itself and go back to where it was. Anyway to do that? Any help would be great!

Comment: Could we get an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @MarkCook i've been looking over all the docs, but i dont even know where to start. it seems like no one has ever asked such a thing, even though its possible.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel

The `position` property under `textchannel` might be a good starting point.  To clarify, in short, what I'd do is create a .json file containing all current channels and their positions, at that point you create a task that checks all your channels ever `x` seconds or minutes and compares the channels that currently exist to your json file of channels that are supposed to exist and have it remake and reposition all missing channels.

Comment: i'm new to discord.py, how would i even make it save all the channels? @MarkCook

Comment: Saving channels isn't a `discord.py` specific feature.  Saving information for persistence is something you do with the python language.  A library isn't designed to do everything, it's designed to assist with a specific aspect of your code.  I suggest looking into the `json` library.  I'm typing up an example, working piece that might be of assistance to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example piece that roughly does what you want it to do.  It is not a perfectly working script but I feel that it's enough to point you in the right direction.

on `on_guild_join` this bot makes a list of all the channels it can see.  (Note that this bot, for my testing, had administrative permissions, you'll need to tinker with your personal permissions to get it to work for you).  Once it scrapes the channels, it saves the information to a .json file.

on `on_guild_channel_delete`, `on_guild_channel_update` and `on_guild_channel_create`, the bot compares the channel that was deleted and checks it against a dictionary of 'expected' channels.  If it matches, the channel/category is recreated and put into the correct category.  This part is a bit buggy and I didn't have the time to get it working perfectly, but this is probably a good exercise for you to try to play around with.

```python
import discord
from discord.utils import get
import json

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = open('token.txt').read()

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    """
    Called whenever our bot is invited into the server
    """

    # Create a dictionary to hold our channels
    guild_channels = {}

    # Get all the channels in the guild that was just joined
    for channel in guild.channels:

        # Determine if channel is a category or not
        if channel.category:
            # Store information in our dictionary (if in category)
            guild_channels[channel.name] = {
                                            'channel_name' : channel.name,
                                            'channel_type' : channel.type.name,
                                            'category': channel.category.name
                                          }
        else:
            # Store information in our dictionary (if is category)
            guild_channels[channel.name] = {
                                            'channel_name' : channel.name,
                                            'channel_type' : channel.type.name,
                                            'category': None
                                          }

    # Save our information to a JSON file for persistence
    with open('./{}_channels.json'.format(guild.id), 'w') as gFile:
        json.dump(guild_channels, gFile, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    """
    Called whenever a channel is deleted
    """

    # Get a list of all expected channels
    with open('./{}_channels.json'.format(channel.guild.id), 'r') as gFile:
        expected_channels = json.load(gFile)
    
    # Check if channel was in expected_channels
    if channel.name in expected_channels:

        # If it's a category, remake the category
        if not expected_channels[channel.name]['category']:
            await channel.guild.create_category(expected_channels[channel.name]['channel_name'])

        # If it wasn't a category, make a channel and put it in the category it's supposed to have
        if channel.category:
            if expected_channels[channel.name]['channel_type'] == 'text':
                await channel.guild.create_text_channel(expected_channels[channel.name]['channel_name'], category=get(channel.guild.channels, name=expected_channels[channel.name]['category']))
            if expected_channels[channel.name]['channel_type'] == 'voice':
                await channel.guild.create_voice_channel(expected_channels[channel.name]['channel_name'], category=get(channel.guild.channels, name=expected_channels[channel.name]['category']))

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    
    # Get a list of all expected channels
    with open('./{}_channels.json'.format(channel.guild.id), 'r') as gFile:
        expected_channels = json.load(gFile)

    if channel.name in expected_channels:
        if channel.category != expected_channels[channel.name]['category']:
            await channel.edit(category=get(channel.guild.channels, name=expected_channels[channel.name]['category']))

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_update(before,after):
    
    # Get a list of all expected channels
    with open('./{}_channels.json'.format(before.guild.id), 'r') as gFile:
        expected_channels = json.load(gFile)

    # Move channels to their respective categories
    if before.name in expected_channels:
        if before.category != expected_channels[before.name]['category']:
            await after.edit(category=get(before.guild.channels, name=expected_channels[before.name]['category']))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

client.run(TOKEN)
```